# morph target uv maps

Tags: export, conversion, unreal-engine

Unreal Engine uses materials and UV maps for static mesh morph targets. Can I setup my model to facilitate this functionality? You can see the documentation page for Unreal Engine here.

The documentation is for 3DS Max so I have no idea how to convert this to blender, as I have no access to 3DS Max.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Content/Types/StaticMeshes/MorphTargets/index.html

Cheers, Rigel

Comment: It doesnt say anything about UV maps, but UV coordinates, I assume that can be done with shapekeys in blender.

Comment: I thought shape keys required a skeletal mesh.

Comment: Shapekeys are used for mesh deformation. It looks like they are using RGB colors for vertices to define the position is 3D space, and morphing the mesh by changing the colors. I dont see there anything related to UV maps.

Comment: okay. thanks for the helpful comments. I'll hit up epic and see if they can create an implementation that does not require a script for a single application in order to implement static mesh animations in Unreal Engine.

Cheers, Rigel